# group by count from left joined table

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

Here's my query:

```
$select d.*, 
count(a.id) as delivered
from `dealerships` as d
left join `assignments` as a on (a.id_dealership = d.id)
group by d.id
order by d.name asc
```

now this works, but it is counting duplicate leads. when I add `a.id_lead` to the group by, it messes up everything. There is a column in the `assignments` table called `id_lead` and I want the count() (`delivered`) to count the total of assignments grouped by `id_lead`, so that it ignores more than 1 row with the same `id_lead`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean? :

```
select d.*, 
count(distinct a.id_lead) as delivered
from `dealerships` as d
left join `assignments` as a on (a.id_dealership = d.id)
group by d.id
order by d.name asc
```

It's the same as your query, except that instead of counting the *total number of records* in `a`, it will only count the number of *distinct non-null values* in `a.id_lead`.

(If that's *not* what you mean, then please clarify.)